# Drupal How to add the dropdown in the search box

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

by default we have drupal search box,

i want to add one dropdown , that should contain the content types(like page,story,article)

i know there is a lot of modules, but i want to know, using hook module, i want to add the

dropdown,

i want to do it with only hook methodm

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a preprocess for the search form function in your theme's template.php file. 
There's a nice example of it [here](http://systemseed.com/blog/how-customise-search-box-drupal-6).

Comment: i just followed the above link step, and i added the phptemplate_preprocess_search_theme_form function in garland theme inside template.php, but am not find any changes in the search box,

Comment: Still am not got exact solution, for my problem,